# Convert a string into a name class

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to pass a string to make work a class like this:

```
mouvement = New MyClass();

public virtual void PlaySprite(string mouvement) 
{
    //Launch an animation named mouvement
    sprite.Play(MyClass mouvement)
}
```

I'll need to convert the string. Is it possible?

I'd like to avoid doing this, especially as i have 100 moves

```
mouvement1 = New MyClass();
mouvement2 = New MyClass();

public virtual void PlaySprite(int number) 
{
    if (number == 1)
    {
        //Launch an animation named mouvement
        sprite.Play(mouvement1)
    }
    else if (number == 2)
    {
        sprite.Play(mouvement2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know `C` has that fancy syntax!

Comment: is this c# i presume?

Comment: what does the string represent about the class?  is it the name of the class?

Comment: What's a class?  What's a virtual?  This isn't like any C I know.

Comment: Yes, it is the name of the class.

Comment: What should `PlaySprite(myClass mouvement)` do?

Comment: Is there a comma missing there? Are you trying to just make a *new* instance of the class called (the value of) mouvement?

Comment: sprite.Play(Myclass mouvement) launch an animation. I'd like to launch it from an another class from a string.

Comment: I'm sorry, that still doesn't make a lot of sense. If this *wasn't* possible, how would that call have to work?

Comment: I call PlaySprite from another class to launch the mouvement animation loaded in this class.

Comment: This is still very unclear. What is a sample value for "movement"? You can't pass a parameter like you are doing, so does it just take an *instance* of `MyClass`?

Comment: movement is an instance of MyClass (like when you call something like ContentManager content or GameTime gametime). I'll need to call its name using a string from another class.

Comment: @Pilispring ok, so you are trying to magically access some *existing* instance of the class (based on a variable name), or just create a new one?

Comment: i'm trying to launch an existing instance based on the variable name

Comment: @Pilispring Any reason you can't just pass that instance in? How would it know which class to look for that variable name in?

Comment: Okay, I think I finally get what you are saying. Let me know if my answer helps!

Comment: I can't pass it because i have hundreds instances of that class and i'd like to avoid the loading of them in both main classes.

Comment: @Pilispring Passing doesn't cause a "load". It just passes a reference. It will be *way* more efficient than trying to use reflection to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

Just accept a parameter of type `MyClass`. No string necessary:

```
public virtual void PlaySprite(MyClass animation) 
{
    //You already have what you need in animation
    sprite.Play(animation);
}

//Usage
PlaySprite(movement);
PlaySprite(movement1);
PlaySprite(movement2);
```

Note that passing a reference does not cause a new reference to be created, or any "load" to occur. You incur the extra cost of a variable on the stack, but you already had that on your string.

Using reflection to get these objects from the calling class would be *far, far* more expensive,and is totally not necessary.

Comment: This is the thing i use to do when i have to call the method in the same class.
However, when trying to call the method from another class (where the animation hadn't been load) they tell me that "animation doesn't exist".
What kind of information can i pass to make him understand "i want this animation loaded in another class to play" ?

Comment: @Pilispring That doesn't make any sense. You are passing an object reference, the source/destination *shouldn't* matter. Unfortunately, I don't really see enough information to give you a solid answer as to what is wrong with your attempt.